# i want to write .j2c file

Tags: image-processing, freeimage, jpeg2000

With FreeImage I want to create a j2c file for DCINEMA and test it, however, the result file is not compatible with j2c.

IfanView (image software) says "result.j2c" is a jp2 file with an incorrect extension and renames it from result.j2c to result.jp2.

I don't understand how to create a j2c file.

My code is below:

```
RGBQUAD color;
GetDims(  hOutputImage, &iWidth, &iHeight );

UCHAR* pSrc = ( UCHAR* )(Image->GetRaw( hOutputImage) );
FIBITMAP* bitmap = FreeImage_Allocate(iWidth, iHeight, 24);

for ( int i = 0; i < iHeight; i++) {
    for( int j = 0 ; j < iWidth; j++) {
        color.rgbRed =  *( pSrc + 0 );
        color.rgbGreen =  *( pSrc + 1 );
        color.rgbBlue =  *( pSrc + 2 );
        FreeImage_SetPixelColor(bitmap, j, i , &color);
        pSrc += 4;
    }
}

static int index = 0;
CString fileName;
fileName.Format("c:\\%06d.j2c", index++);
const char *ss = (LPSTR)(LPCTSTR) fileName;

FreeImage_Save(FIF_J2K, bitmap, ss, J2K_DEFAULT );
```

What should I do?